# How to set textbox to accept only numbers within certain range

Tags: javascript, html

The range could be for example 5 to 10
This is what I've done so far but it's still not doing what I want

```
<script>
function checkpattern(elem)
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");

    if(textbox.value.length<=10 && textbox.value.length>=5)
    {
        alert("5 to 10");
    }
    else
    {
        if(!elem.value.match('^'+elem.getAttribute('pattern')+'$'))
        {
            alert('Accepts digits only');
        }
    }
}
</script>

<input type = "text" name = "amt" maxlength = "10" pattern = [0-9] onchange = checkpattern(this) placeholder="Enter Amount" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Amount '" required="">
```

Comment: Do you want numbers that are only 5 to 10 digits long or numbers with a value between 5 and 10?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `minlength` it wont let you submit it unless it has more than 5 characters

```
<input type = "text" name = "amt" minlength="5" maxlength = "10" pattern = [0-9] onchange = checkpattern(this) placeholder="Enter Amount" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Amount '" required="">
```

if you want to set it as an amount(numbers) you can work with `min` and `max`:

```
<input type = "number" name = "amt" min="5" max = "10" pattern = [0-9] onchange = checkpattern(this) placeholder="Enter Amount" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Amount '" required="">
```

Comment: remember that if you want it to be bigger that 5 digits you shouls change min to 10000 and 10 digits at maximun should be max="9999999999"

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems in your code, if else is wrong & you are also not passing the input value correctly

```
 <script>
function checkpattern(elem)
        {

            if(elem<=10 && elem>=5)
            {
            alert("5 to 10");
            }
                if(!elem.match(/^\d+$/))
            {
                alert('Accepts digits only');
            }

        }
</script>
<input type = "text" name = "amt" maxlength = "10" pattern = [0-9] onchange = checkpattern(this.value) placeholder="Enter Amount" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Amount '" required="">
```